# How to change button text colour when an alertView is presenting Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

The login button title colour is white initially, I want to change the title colour of the login button when an alert view is presented. Is it possible to change it to white(like not pressed on it)? When I press OK of alert view it will automatically become white. But can I change it while the alert view is presenting?

Comment: button title colour is white initially:  Is it possible to change it to white: When I press OK it will automatically become white: changing color white to white?

Comment: set once again your title text first, then set the title color
e.g
`self.button.setTitle("re_title", for: .normal)` then
`self.button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)`

Comment: You need to show us the code you have written. It appears you are presenting the alert before the button returns to its normal state... but we can't help without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: A button has multiple states. Change the title color of your button for the `selected` state and that's it.